# git merge - file path change detected but not updated in working/staging area of git

Tags: java, git, macos

I am facing one strange issue with git merge.
I merged master changes in my branch 'abc' as follows :-

```
git checkout abc
git merge -squash master
```

After this i checked git status, it says :-

> renamed:    xyz/PQR/Hello.java -> xyz/pqr/Hello.java

As you can see above master had renamed folder PQR->pqr and also updated contents of file Hello.java.

Now the interesting thing i noticed are as below :-

1. My working area still has PQR directory only, when i check using ls
   command . i am not able to cd to pqr directory but i can do ls on
   pqr/Hello.java
2. master changes in Hello.java are present in my
   working area's Hello.java .
3. In eclipse's stage area view i see both
   PQR/Hello.java and pqr/Hello.java as unstaged changes but when on
   command line, using git status i dont see any unstaged changes .
4. i think inodes of both PQR/Hello.java and pqr/Hello.java is same .

Why is git not replacing PQR directory with pqr ? How can i force it ?
Let me know if more info is needed to solve this mystery ( for me atleast :)).

Comment: Your tags indicate that you're on osx (which IIRC has a case-sensitive filesystem), but still it sounds like an issue with filename/path case-sensitivity.  Do you have a value set for `core.ignoreCase` in your git configuration?

Comment: yes, i am on mac. core.ignoreCase is set to true.

Comment: So core.ignoreCase tells git to try to play nice with case-insensitive filesystems (e.g. Windows).  That's why you're seeing inconsistent information about whether anything changed.  Is the repo also used/accessed on Windows? (Just trying to figure out why that config would be set...)

Comment: yeah .. this repo is used on windows as well. I am not very clear how this is related to my issue?

Comment: On windows, the file system is case insensitive - so `xyz/PQR/Hello.java` is the same file as `xyz/pqr/Hello.java`.  You may still have changes *in* the file, but when the filesystem is interpreted as case-sensitive git would say "`xyz/PQR/Hello.java` was deleted and `xyz/pqr/Hello.java` was created" (or a rename occurred, depending on rename detection); but when the filesystem is interpreted as case-insensitive it would say "no change" and would accept whichever capitalization happens to be on the work tree. Even though you're on OSX, your config tells git to ignore filename case

Comment: ok . I set it to false and tried again. Now i see PQR directory in untracked file list in git  and pqr directory still not available in working dir. Eclipse behaviour remains same.

Comment: OSX file systems default to the *same* behavior as Windows file systems: if you ask the system to create a file named `xyz/pqr/Hello.java` when there is already an `xyz/PQR/` directory, the system uses the existing `xyz/PQR/` directory. Changing `core.ignoreCase` is not recommended: Git sets this when you first create the repository (by `git init` or `git clone`) based on what the underlying file system's behavior is.

Comment: ok .. thanks .. so what is the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok .. so here is what i did.
I copied my git repo on a file system formatted with MacOS(Journed,Case sensitive) and then tried to merge. With this , git was able to recognize the renaming and i was able to commit without doing any manual stuff.
Thanks to all those who helped to understand this problem.